# React.ReactNode to react element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I have an object of type React.ReactNode, and I want to:

1) Check if it is of type React.ReactElement

2) If yes, then I want to create a ReactElement Object equal to the node

for part 1, I am using React.isValidElement (not sure if necessary)

for part 2, i'm not sure how to do at all

In the end, I need to be able to check if a certain class is contained within the node if it is an element if that is of help. I'm assuming I need to create the ReactElement object to do this but if not that is okay as well.

Answer (score -1):

First, you're using TypeScript (at least it looks that way by the tags) - so, ideally, you wouldn't even need to make a runtime check on the type of the object, you can do it at compile time

```
interface PropTypes {
  something: React.ReactElement<...>
}

const M = ({ something }: PropTypes) => { 

}
```

Second, in order to create a ReactElement from it, you can use `React.cloneElement(...)`

```
const cElement = React.cloneElement(something, something.props, [...children])
```

Comment: This does not work with the type React.ReactNode unfortunately

Comment: hm, interesting - what about `React.createElement`?

Comment: TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'createElement'